# No OpenGL context found in the current thread, Textures

Tags: java, opengl, textures

```
    package game;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import org.lwjgl.opengl.EXTTextureFilterAnisotropic;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.GL12;
import org.lwjgl.util.glu.MipMap;
import org.newdawn.slick.opengl.Texture;
import org.newdawn.slick.opengl.TextureLoader;
import org.newdawn.slick.util.ResourceLoader;

public class TextureStore {

    private static final boolean USE_MIPMAPS = true;

    private Map<String, Texture> textureMap;

    public TextureStore() {
        textureMap = new HashMap<String, Texture>();
    }

    public Texture getTexture(String path) {
        // Return the texture if it already exists in the map
        if(textureMap.containsKey(path)) {
            return textureMap.get(path);
        } else {
            try {
                Texture tex = TextureLoader.getTexture("PNG", ResourceLoader.getResourceAsStream(path));

                if(USE_MIPMAPS)
                    createMipmaps(tex);

                textureMap.put(path, tex);
                return tex;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        return null;
    }

    /* Function which generates mipmaps. Found on the internet. */
    public static void createMipmaps(Texture tex) {
        tex.bind();

        int width = (int)tex.getImageWidth();
        int height = (int)tex.getImageHeight();

        byte[] texbytes = tex.getTextureData();
        int components = texbytes.length / (width*height);

        ByteBuffer texdata = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(texbytes.length);
        texdata.put(texbytes);
        texdata.rewind();

        GL11.glTexParameteri(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL11.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL11.GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR);
        GL11.glTexParameteri(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL11.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL11.GL_LINEAR);

        GL11.glTexParameteri(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL11.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL12.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
        GL11.glTexParameteri(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL11.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL12.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

        GL11.glTexParameteri(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, EXTTextureFilterAnisotropic.GL_TEXTURE_MAX_ANISOTROPY_EXT, 8);

        MipMap.gluBuild2DMipmaps(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, components, width, height, components==3 ? GL11.GL_RGB : GL11.GL_RGBA, GL11.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,texdata);
    }

    static float CUBE_TEXTUREMAP_WIDTH = 1024;

    public static Rectf getTexRect(int x, int y) {
        float pixelX = (x + 1) * 2 + x * 32;
        float pixelY = (y + 1) * 2 + y * 32;

        return new Rectf(pixelX / CUBE_TEXTUREMAP_WIDTH, pixelY / CUBE_TEXTUREMAP_WIDTH, (pixelX + 31) / CUBE_TEXTUREMAP_WIDTH, (pixelY + 31) / CUBE_TEXTUREMAP_WIDTH);

    }
}
```

This is the TextureStore.java code..
in line 32:

```
Texture tex = TextureLoader.getTexture("PNG", ResourceLoader.getResourceAsStream(path));
```

he shows me an error:
No OpenGL context found in the current thread.

Whenever i call this function "getTexture" it throws me out.

I don't understand what i'm doing wrong..

Comment: Have you tried making an OpenGL context current in the thread before calling that?

Comment: Are you trying to create the textures in a separate thread? Or are you accidently trying to create them before the GL context was created? How (and when) do you actually create the context?